# Boost bimap won't compile: Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost

I'm trying to use a boost::bimap to provide bi-directional mapping of some node numbers. I have been using boost unordered maps for a few other things, and have no problems using them. I'm on visual studio 2010.

However I get a ton of template errors whenever I try and use a bimap. Even cutting and pasting the code from the examples at [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/bimap/example/step_by_step.cpp) I get the same masses of template problems. E.g: I inserted this code, direct from the examples:

```
typedef boost::bimap< int, std::string > bm_type;
bm_type bm;

bm.insert( bm_type::value_type(1, "one" ) );
bm.insert( bm_type::value_type(2, "two" ) );
```

and I get about 750 lines of errors, starting with this:

```
c:\data\boost\boost_1_56_0\boost\bimap\relation\mutant_relation.hpp(94): error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
1>          c:\data\boost\boost_1_56_0\boost\bimap\relation\mutant_relation.hpp(157) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::bimaps::relation::detail::relation_storage<LeftType,RightType,force_mutable>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              LeftType=boost::bimaps::tags::tagged<const int,boost::bimaps::relation::member_at::left>,
1>              RightType=boost::bimaps::tags::tagged<const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,boost::bimaps::relation::member_at::right>,
1>              force_mutable=false
1>          ]
```

and ending in

```
IteratorToBaseConverter=boost::bimaps::container_adaptor::support::iterator_facade_to_base<boost::bimaps::detail::map_view_iterator<boost::bimaps::relation::member_at::right,boost::bimaps::detail::bimap_core<int,std::string,boost::mpl::na,boost::mpl::na,boost::mpl::na>>,boost::bimaps::detail::const_map_view_iterator<boost::bimaps::relation::member_at::right,boost::bimaps::detail::bimap_core<int,std::string,boost::mpl::na,boost::mpl::na,boost::mpl::na>>>,
1>              IteratorFromBaseConverter=boost::mpl::na,
1>              ReverseIteratorFromBaseConverter=boost::mpl::na,
1>              ValueToBaseConverter=boost::bimaps::relation::detail::pair_to_relation_functor<boost::bimaps::relation::member_at::right,boost::bimaps::relation::mutant_relation<boost::bimaps::tags::tagged<const int,boost::bimaps::relation::member_at::left>,boost::bimaps::tags::tagged<const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,boost::bimaps::relation::member_at::right>,boost::bimaps::detail::manage_additional_parameters<boost::mpl::na,boost::mpl::na,boost::mpl::na>::case_NNN::additional_info,true>>,
1>              ValueFromBaseConverter=boost::bimaps::relation::support::get_pair_functor<boost::bimaps::relation::member_at::right,boost::bimaps::relation::mutant_relation<boost::bimaps::tags::tagged<const int,boost::bimaps::relation::member_at::left>,boost::bimaps::tags::tagged<const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,boost::bimaps::relation::member_at::right>,boost::bimaps::detail::manage_additional_parameters<boost::mpl::na,boost::mpl::na,boost::mpl::na>::case_NNN::additional_info,true>>
1>          ]
1>c:\data\my_code.cpp(194): error C2665: 'boost::bimaps::relation::mutant_relation<TA,TB,Info,force_mutable>::mutant_relation' : none of the 5 overloads could convert all the argument types
1>          with
1>          [
1>              TA=boost::bimaps::tags::tagged<const int,boost::bimaps::relation::member_at::left>,
1>              TB=boost::bimaps::tags::tagged<const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,boost::bimaps::relation::member_at::right>,
1>              Info=boost::bimaps::detail::manage_additional_parameters<boost::mpl::na,boost::mpl::na,boost::mpl::na>::case_NNN::additional_info,
1>              force_mutable=false
1>          ]
1>          c:\data\boost\boost_1_56_0\boost\bimap\relation\mutant_relation.hpp(265): could be 'boost::bimaps::relation::mutant_relation<TA,TB,Info,force_mutable>::mutant_relation(const int,const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              TA=boost::bimaps::tags::tagged<const int,boost::bimaps::relation::member_at::left>,
1>              TB=boost::bimaps::tags::tagged<const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,boost::bimaps::relation::member_at::right>,
1>              Info=boost::bimaps::detail::manage_additional_parameters<boost::mpl::na,boost::mpl::na,boost::mpl::na>::case_NNN::additional_info,
1>              force_mutable=false,
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(int, int)'
```

The same code on a linux machine compiles without errors. Any help most appreciated! 
As noted in the comments below, the line

```
  boost::bimap< int, std::string > test;
```

on its own will trigger similar errors. Ignore the error above regarding (int, int), I had left an earlier line in the code which was using a boost::bimap. Now removed, no significant change in the volume of errors.

Comment: Will it compile if you change `bm.insert( bm_type::value_type(1, "one" ) );` to `bm.insert( bm_type::value_type(1, std::string("one") ) );`?

Comment: Nope. In fact it won't compile when all I do is declare a bimap:  `boost::bimap< int, std::string > test;` on its own causes the same raft of errors

Comment: that would be a supported platforms kind of issue. Check that VS2010 is supported with the version of boost you use. It's no problem with VS2013/boost 1_56 (although it takes over a minute to compile, WTF)

Comment: urgh. I tried a separate executable with just the example code in it, and it compiles without an issue. So something in my setup is borking the building of bimaps..this is not going to be fun